# Cannot access control on another form even though Modifier is set to PUBLIC

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to access a on my `MainForm` from another Form. This control is a FlowLayoutPanel, and I have set its Access Modifier to `Public`. I don't know why I can't access it from another form, because this method has always worked for me in the past.

MainForm.cs:

```
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(var editor = new Editor())
    {
        editor.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Editor.cs:

```
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = MainForm.flow.Count;
}
```

Why can I not access this control from another form - even though its modifier is set to `public`?

Comment: is MainForm the name of an instance variable or the class of your MainForm?

Comment: MainForm is the actual Form. I got sick of having Form1 as the "main form".

Comment: but is it just the name of the class, or do you have a variable called MainForm that is a reference to that form?

Comment: @Zohar, Oh, no it's just the name of the Class.

Comment: In that case, look at martin's answer. he is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are accessing the control/property wrong.

You should do it like this.

MainForm.cs

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var frm = new Editor();
  frm.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

Editor.cs

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var f = (this.Owner as MainForm);
    int count = f.flow.Count;
    MessageBox.Show(count.ToString());
}
```